Error CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing in Django app
Configuring Django restframework CORS Headers
My application tries to read a file from an external storage service and receives a response:

A request from an outside source is blocked: The Single source policy prohibits reading a remote resource on <EXTERNAL_LINK>. Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing. Forbidden 403

Django settings
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'rest_framework',
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://myapp.site', #  no SSL cert
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
    "HEAD",
)

answer dev tools
XHRHEAD
<EXTERNAL_LINK>
CORS Missing Allow Origin

    
HEAD
<EXTERNAL_LINK>
Status
403
Version HTTP/2
Referrer policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin

    content-length
        15
    content-type
        application/octet-stream
    date
        Tue, 30 Apr 2024 16:46:05 GMT
    server
        nginx
    X-Firefox-Spdy
        h2
        
    Accept
        */*
    Accept-Encoding
        gzip, deflate, br
    Connection
        keep-alive
    Host
        <DOMAIN_EXTERNAL_LINK>
    Origin
        http://myapp.site
    Referer
        http://myapp.site/
    Sec-Fetch-Dest
        empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode
        cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site
        cross-site
    User-Agent
        Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0

Please help me solve the problem

You have only your app site link in the list of allowed origins, you need to also add the external storage service domain to your list of allowed origins.
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    ...,
    <DOMAIN_EXTERNAL_LINK>,
    ...,
]


No, it didn't have any effect
It seems to me that the external source does not send the required header Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response, so this problem arises
